# how to refresh mapview in iphones through Objective C

Tags: iphone

I have a mapview in my application.I have a Textfield where i type the location i need..when i press UIButton Item named GO..it searches and points to the location i have typed in textfield..now i want to refresh the mapview..as in i want the same view which was before i type anything in textfield..how do i do that???

Answer (score 1):

Save the value of the `MKMapView.region` property and restore it to its previous value.

Answer (score -1):

destroy the current mapview object using

[mapview release];

and then create a new mapview